# Simple Javascript to play consecutive EXTERNAL videos from different players (youtube/brightcove/break/vimeo)

Tags: javascript, arrays, video, youtube, brightcove

I need to make an html page that will play video 1(youtube), and once video 1 is done, will instantly play video 2(vimeo), and once video 2 is done, will play video 3(brightcove). The thing is I want to do this with external videos from vimeo/youtube/brightcove players which means the videos will not be in my directory. I thought utilizing javascript to put the videos into an array and changing the embed source per each video would be sufficient. Unfortunately I have not been able to come across any examples that would help me realize this. (Although I did find this very useful resource: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html) Sadly this resource is for local video files, not embedded ones from different players.

can anyone point me in the right direction?